# Exception - You have requested a non-existent service "indragunawan.facade.container"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the package "indragunawan/facade-bundle"and it works well for me when I use it in the "dev" environment, but when I want to use it in the production environment, it throws me an error: `Exception - You have requested a non-existent service "indragunawan.facade.container"`.

When I test the code shown below, it returns true if it is in "dev" and false when it is in "prod".

```php
/**
 * @author Indra Gunawan <hello@indra.my.id>
 */
final class IndragunawanFacadeBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        dump(
            $this->container->has('indragunawan.facade.container')
        );
        die;
        AbstractFacade::setFacadeContainer($this->container->get('indragunawan.facade.container'));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new AddFacadePass());
    }
}
```

Ideally,
`$this->container->get('indragunawan.facade.container')` return the `ServiceLocator` object.

Answer (score 0):

check if the bundle is well loaded on PROD environment or just in DEV.

Comment: Yes, it is registered in AppKernel.php

Comment: In this case, It will be better to share with us you class AppKernel, and the code on which you use the service

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simpler than I expected. I just had to delete the entire `app/var/cache` folder and the files were regenerated again with no errors.